# Mongodb convert object values ​to top level string field

Tags: mongodb, bson

I have the following query **mongoDB**

```
{
    "name": "juan",
    "class": {
        "name": "person"  // is the field of another collection.
    }
}
```

and what I want to achieve is the following

```
{
    "name": "juan",
    "class": "person"
}
```

But I need everyone's support to achieve the above.

Comment: Try to look up `$projection` in docs.

Comment: @ Márius Rak thanks i will look for information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is for the data to be returned in the structure you specified, you can use a projection with a find query:

```
db.collection.find({}, { name: 1, class: '$class.name' });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Adelekam Thanks for sharing your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to update the multiple documents, then bellow query will be helpful:

```js
db.collection.update(
  { },
  [
    {
      $set: {
        'class': '$class.name'
      }
    }
  ],
  { multi:true }
)
```

Comment: @ingShravil.py Thanks for sharing your answer.

Comment: I would like to suggest you, to be clear in the OP from next time. As in this case it was not clear whether you wanted to `update` or to `find`.

Comment: @ingShavil.py Sorry, I will be more precise with my questions, but thanks for your reply.